# Android studio - Error when install android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio on windows seven but when the install is finishing get me bellow error :

Why show me Chinese message and get me error?

[image]

[image]

NOTICE : My system type is 32 bit, and I install jdk 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to set the language of your system to English?

You can find the steps [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/change-the-display-language).